# How can I make list of Map

Tags: flutter, dart

> I have list of names want to add them to map and add each record of this map to list Like this

```
List<String> items = [
  'Item1',
  'Item2',
  'Item3',
  'Item4',
  'Item5',
  'Item6',
  'Item7',
  'Item8',
];
List all=[];
Map <String, dynamic>test={};
me(){
    for(int i=0; i<items.length;i++){
      test["one"]=items[i];
      test["check"]=false;
      all.add(test);
      
    }
  test["check"]=false); });
  print(all);
```

> The output was

```
[{one: Item8, check: false}, {one: Item8, check: false}, {one: Item8, check: false}, {one: Item8, check: false}, {one: Item8, check: false}, {one: Item8, check: false}, {one: Item8, check: false}, {one: Item8, check: false}]
```

> The item8 was always repeated but I want this output

```
[{one: Item1, check: false}, {one: Item2, check: false}, {one: Item3, check: false}, {one: Item4, check: false}, {one: Item5, check: false}, {one: Item6, check: false}, {one: Item7, check: false}, {one: Item8, check: false}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```dart
final results = items.map((e) => {"one": e, "check": false}).toList();
```

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> items = [
    'Item1',
    'Item2',
    'Item3',
    'Item4',
    'Item5',
    'Item6',
    'Item7',
    'Item8',
  ];
  
  final results = items.map((e) => {"one": e, "check": false}).toList();
  print(results);
}
```

Prints:

```dart
[{one: Item1, check: false}, {one: Item2, check: false}, {one: Item3, check: false}, {one: Item4, check: false}, {one: Item5, check: false}, {one: Item6, check: false}, {one: Item7, check: false}, {one: Item8, check: false}]
```

---

Or: using your approach with a `for` loop:

```dart
final results = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    results.add({"one": items[i], "check": false});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```dart
final all = items
    .map(
      (item) => {
        'one': item,
        'check': false,
      },
    )
    .toList();
```